# Servlet writing file contains binary at the end

Tags: java, servlets

I have a servlet to let user download a file from server. The original file is human readable, but the downloaded file alwyas contains binary content at the end of the file.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
String fileName = session.getAttribute("download").toString();
System.out.println("Download file " + fileName);
File file = new File(fileName);
FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);

response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + file.getName());

ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
byte[] bytes = new byte[BYTES_DOWNLOAD];

while (fileIn.read(bytes, 0, BYTES_DOWNLOAD) != -1) {
    out.write(bytes, 0, BYTES_DOWNLOAD);
}

out.flush();
out.close();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small bug in your code:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[BYTES_DOWNLOAD];
int count;
while ( (count = fileIn.read(bytes)) != -1) {
    out.write(bytes, 0, count);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! that is the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What binary content do you see? Is it perhaps the line endings in the file, if any?